# Angular p-paginator bug with pages and rows

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, primeng, primeng-datatable

In my backed application (Spring boot), I have a method who get a Pageable (page and size)
when I implement my table in angular, when I pass just the page with the normal size of rows are ok, but when I change the rows it will get a random page without any reason, somebody knows if is a bug?
My spring controller:

```
  @GetMapping("/getAll")
public ResponseEntity<Page<PersonModel>> getAll(Integer page, Integer size) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(personService.personModelList(page, size));
}
```

My angular html:

```
    <p-table #dt [value]="persons" dataKey="id" responsiveLayout="scroll"
         currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {{totalRecords}} persons">
  <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
   .....
</p-table>
<p-paginator
  (onPageChange)="handlePagination($event)"
  [rows]="rows"
  [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,25,50]"
  [totalRecords]="totalRecords"
></p-paginator>
```

my ts:

```
 public handlePagination(paginationData: any): void {
console.log(paginationData)
this.currentPage = paginationData.page + 1;
this.rows=paginationData.rows;
this.getAll(this.currentPage,this.rows);
}
```

what I see when I just change the page: [page changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq7OP.png)

what I see when I just change the rows (it change the pages too without any reason): [rows change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N69NT.png)

It shoud't get the other result of next pages without get the old result?